# How to chain a queryset together in Django correctly

Tags: python, django

Using the example below, I'm trying to use a queryset and append/chain filters together. To my understanding last `queryset.count()` should have just 1 instance, but it always had the original 10 in it.

Expected output of last `queryset.count()` is 1:

```
# Set a default queryset.
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = super(UserMixin, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
    queryset.count() # 10 instacnes
    queryset.filter(id=1)
    queryset.count() # 10 instacnes excpeted 1
```

I can solve this problem I think by:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(id=1)
```

Is this the correct way or there a way to chain them correctly where I can add the queryset object around?

Comment: Try `queryset.filter(id=1).count()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never assign the filter to anything so it doesn't update it

```
 queryset = queryset.filter(id=1)
```

Yes this is the correct way because you are creating a new query, otherwise you need to call the count on the end of the previous filter call

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to make sure there was no a function that auto assigned i.e self-reference itself back or something, but that makes sense. Thanks you again.